# GetElementById Fail .. only on a particular page though

Tags: html, vb.net

I am trying to enter information in to a login form on this site: http://www.clover.com/home/login

I am building a windows form App in VB.net, vs 2015, and using the WebBrowser control.  I have the following code in my WB controls DocumentCompleted event:

```
Dim PWord As HtmlElement
PWord = wb.Document.GetElementById("password")

If PWord IsNot Nothing Then
    PWord.InnerText = "password"
Else
    MsgBox("fail..Again!")
End If
```

For the life of me, I can not determine why I can not find the "password" field (or Email field, login button, etc) on this page by their ID's. I get the fail message no matter which element's ID I try to use.

A little background: I am completely blind and use a screen reader (jaws for windows) to access my computer, so if I have royally screwed up this post (wrong section of the forums, incorrect use of link/code tags, etc) I greatly apologize.

Comment: @Forklift : Nope. That is valid VB.NET code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: well .. the code works, I have tested it with other pages (Gmail login page for example) .. it just wont find this element, on this page ..

Comment: Strange... Your code looks alright. Unfortunately though, I don't have access to an IDE so I can't test this at the moment.

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with the element being nested in so many tags, but my own HTML experience is very limited .. since the page doesn't seem to have frames it should still be found by ID?

Comment: Nested tags nor frames matter. `GetElementById()` should find it in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that site loads data asynchronously after the initial page load.  The workaround would be to have a timer that gets enabled in your DocumentCompleted event.  The tick handler should be your current code.  Three seconds seems to be enough of an interval:

```
Private Sub wb_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles wb.DocumentCompleted
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim PWord As HtmlElement = wb.Document.GetElementById("password")

    If PWord IsNot Nothing Then
        PWord.InnerText = "password"
    Else
        MsgBox("fail..Again!")
    End If

    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

Comment: Having a delay like that is not very reliable... If the website continues to load data then `DocumentCompleted` should be fired multiple times. Try checking if `wb.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete` or `wb.IsBusy = False`, then execute the code and see if it works. If it does, then it replaces the timer and is also more reliable.

Comment: Alternatively you can have a timer that checks every tick if the element exists.

Comment: Your solution worked beautifully.  I will add some checking because I agree that guessing when to have the tick is not very elegant, but the answer was spot on.

Comment: Thanks.  I do like @VisualVincent 's recommendation about not doing Timer1.Stop unless the control exists.